# link label to checkbox using CSS only

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5qm1a4pz/ , I am using for/id to select to link the checkbox and label explicitly. The idea is when text "click me to select checkbox" is clicked, the checkbox gets selected. However, it doesnt work in all browsers and in outlook web mail as well. **How can I traverse the ":checked" feature in CSS to link the label text to the checkbox input? I want to click on the label text i.e. "click me to select checkbox" to select the checkbox.**

Please note that wrapping the checkbox inside a label works, but I cannot use it as the checkbox is part of a table.

code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
<style>
#content {
    display: none;
}

input:checked ~ #content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>


<body style="height:50px">

    <label for="show">Click Me to select checkbox</label>
    <input type=checkbox id="show">
    
    <span id="content">Text visible when checkbox is clicked </span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "*[It doesn't] work in all browsers*" - in which browser(s) does it not work? (The Outlook desktop client, so far as I remember, renders emails using the MS Word rendering engine, which rules out most of HTML since about 2005 (from memory); I don't know how the online 365 version works with HTML emails, unfortunately). Further, Mark Robbins (at: https://www.goodemailcode.com/) may have some useful advice on his site, developed in response to working with email clients.

Comment: It doesnt work in primitive IE browser versions. I understand that outlook desktop uses MS word as its rendering engine. However, I am talking about, outlook web, it uses webkit to render and the checkbox works fine in outlook web. I am struggling to link the label text to the checkbox - thats the only problem.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: For oldish browser, you need to wrap input and span into the label  `<label for="show">Click Me to select checkbox 
    <input type=checkbox id="show"> 
    <span id="content">Text visible when checkbox is clicked </span>
    </label>` , **but** the selector `input:checked ~ #content` will probably be not implemented in those browsers. give it a try to find out.

Comment: I did check it in the past. It doesnt work in my case. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Could your code reflect the comment you made saying it's in a table.

Comment: @AHaworth, here is teh fiddle of the table : https://jsfiddle.net/k45fvnho/ - clicking on the checkbox hides and shows data. However, I am not able to link the label "Click Me" to the checkbox. Checkbox by default will obviously be hidden.